# How to get original raw email body from gmail using imap?

Tags: gmail, imap

I was able to connect to Gmail through IMAP and parse as well, but in the email body I am getting Gmail specific contents like `<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr">` and all `class` attributes in elements are removed. Is there any way we can really get raw email data as it was sent from Gmail IMAP servers?

Answer (score 0):

I get that too, even on my self-hosted mail server, because on the order of a quarter of all human email is composed by gmail users.

I just tested `x uid fetch 999999 body.peek[]` for a message from [Honeybadger](http://honeybadger.io), on a gmail account, and it did not contain gmail-specific tags.